# Python nested class definition results in endless recursion... what did I do wrong here?

Tags: python, class, oop, pandas

I am writing a program in Python that opens input files, does some simple text parsing, and outputs. The input comes as an ASCII file with several similarly formatted blocks of text. So, I thought I'd use this as an opportunity to get the hang of defining my own classes.

I have a parent class, `pFrame`, that I want to inherit the properties of the `pandas.DataFrame` class. Since my input text files contain two similar (but not identical) types of columnar text, I define two other classes (`pFrameA` and `pFrameB`) that each inherit the parent class. At present the child classes just initialize a few variables; later I can define simple helper methods for one, the other, or both classes as needed.

Here's a trimmed down version of the module I wrote to define these classes:

```
import pandas as pd

class pFrame(pd.DataFrame):
    pass

class pFrameA(pFrame):
    def __init__(self):
        self.units = ('msec', 'psi')
        self.numFormat = (int, float)
        self._gcHeaderStr = "          Time          Cell"


class pFrameB(pFrame):
    def __init__(self):
        self.units = ('in', 'in')
        self.numFormat  = (float, float)
        self._gcHeaderStr = "Disp 1        Disp 2"
```

But when I try to test out these class definitions, Python goes into an endless recursion loop:

```
>>> import pFrameModule
>>> p=pFrameModule.pFrameA()

...
...
    if name in self.columns:
  File "properties.pyx", line 55, in pandas.lib.AxisProperty.__get__ (pandas/lib.c:29248)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2085, in __getattr__
    if name in self.columns:
  File "properties.pyx", line 55, in pandas.lib.AxisProperty.__get__ (pandas/lib.c:29248)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2085, in __getattr__
    if name in self.columns:
  File "properties.pyx", line 55, in pandas.lib.AxisProperty.__get__ (pandas/lib.c:29248)
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Can someone give me a quick pointer to understand what I'm missing?

Comment: These aren't _nested_ classes - these are just classes with inheritance

Comment: Going to need a bit more of your actual code here.

Comment: At the least, you're going to need to call the inherited `__init__`.

Comment: @Eric - sorry. @kwatford - that is all the code you need. Save first block as `pFrameModule.py`, if that wasn't obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modifying your code to the following appears to fix it:

```
import pandas as pd

class pFrame(pd.DataFrame):
    def __init__(self):
        super(pFrame, self).__init__()

class pFrameA(pFrame):
    def __init__(self):
        super(pFrameA, self).__init__()
        self.units = ('msec', 'psi')
        self.numFormat = (int, float)
        self._gcHeaderStr = "          Time          Cell"


class pFrameB(pFrame):
    def __init__(self):
        super(pFrameB, self).__init__()
        self.units = ('in', 'in')
        self.numFormat  = (float, float)
        self._gcHeaderStr = "Disp 1        Disp 2"     


p = pFrameA()
print p._gcHeaderStr    # To prove something is happening
```

I suspect that by neglecting the call to `super` in each of your constructors, you weren't properly initializing the DataFrame class, causing it to break under the scenes.